# trigger.click - several click

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

i want to handle the trigger.click event

this action works once , but how can i handle and edit it

for example click 10 times or click after delay and ....

how  should it  be customize ?

my code :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function dio() {
    $("#bin").append("hi" + "<br>")
  }
</script>
<button id="btn" onclick="dio()">|||</button>
<div id="bin">

</div>

<script>
  $("#btn").trigger('click');
</script>
```

this action print a hi after loading the page , how can i set click count , and time and stop ?

Comment: Can you describe what do you mean when asking for "i set click count , and time and stop"?  It is absolutely not clear. Please, update your question

Comment: trigger.click event , only click once , 
and my main question is how can i 
make trigger.click who clicks more time ,(10 times)
and how can set time(delay) between clicking 
and stop action ( for the last click)

Comment: If you just want do trigger it 10 times then pack it inside a loop, or use setIntervall() and trigger it for example every second

Comment: this is true , but 10 clicks are activated in same time

Comment: i want to have delay by each clicking ,

Comment: @Alex you can set delay in setInteval, the second paramter 1000 for example is 1 sec

Comment: @Alex is it for jquery?

Comment: @Alex You can also use it with jquery, jquery is JavaScript and setInterval is JavaScript. In my answer I made a snippet there you can try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to trigger it every second.
In order to stop the click after ntimes you can add a data field to your button.

The snippet:

```js
function doit() {
    $("#bin").append("hi" + "<br>")
}


setInterval(() => {
    var max = +$("#btn").data('max') - 1;
    if (max >= 0) {
        $("#btn").data('max', max);
        $("#btn").trigger('click');
    } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn" data-max="10" onclick="doit()">|||</button>
<div id="bin">

</div>
```

Comment: this is true, , thx but can you make it for me via jquery completly

Comment: @Alex I am not sure what do you mean by jquery completly. It is already because you don't use DOM manipulation setInterval doesn't change anything to this fact.

Comment: this code works , but this code have lot of warning in phpstorm

Comment: @Alex you can get rid of the var timer because you never use it.

Comment: @Alex the return value of setInterval is not important, you can get rid of it. 
It is only important when you later on want stop it